# How can an object be a member of another object?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

In russell's paradox is stated as $\left \{ x|x \notin x \right \}$

But membership $\in$ is a relation between objects and sets. How can it be a relation between 2 objects ?

Definition from Robert Stoll's book is "Membership is a relation between objects and sets"

Comment: Sets are objects.

Comment: Sets are also objects. In particular, a set may contain sets.

Comment: This book does not *define objects*, any other book suggestions ?

Comment: Within ZFC, all objects are sets and all sets are objects, so this is the same as saying "membership is a relation between sets and sets" ;)

Comment: Set theory that is not naive (and thus avoids Russel's paradox) basically says that everything is a set in one way or another, as to avoid the ill defined (but intuitively sound) notion of objects.

Answer (score 2):

The whole point of sets is to have a mathematical *object* which is itself a collection of other mathematical objects.

Since sets are both sets and objects, the asking if $x\in x$ or $x\notin x$ is a syntactically valid question.

In modern set theory, all objects are sets, and we simply interpret the natural numbers as specific sets, and the real numbers as other sets, and so on. But if you prefer to work in an environment where there are objects which are not sets, then this is fine. It is just immediately the case that $x\notin x$, when $x$ is not a set.

Answer (score 1):

Let $P$ be the set of all subsets of the integers. Then $\{1\} \in P$.